# How can i access in server side AspxGridView combobox selected value

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to access selected value of GridViewDataComboBoxColumn in server side at GridViewUpdated event. Do you have any idea about how can it be?

Here is columns of AspxGridView

```
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn Name="Sprint_id" Caption="Sprint" FieldName="refSprint_id" VisibleIndex="8">
        <PropertiesComboBox ValueType="System.Int32" DataSourceID="sdsSprintler" TextField="adi" ValueField="sprint_id">
        </PropertiesComboBox>
   </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
```

Combo can fill but i couldnt access the selected item in GridView updated event

KR,

Çağın

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
object cat1 = ((ASPxComboBox)grid.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl(
   grid.Columns["Sprint_id"] as GridViewDataComboBoxColumn, "Cat1")).Value;
```

More info here:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1358.aspx

http://search.devexpress.com/?q=%22GridViewDataComboBoxColumn%22